# Conditional pagination li's

Tags: pagination

I've noticed that must paginations in Wordpress are constructed like this:

```
  <nav class="post-nav clear clearfix">

    <ul>
      <li class="previous"><?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Previous', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></li>
      <li class="next"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Next' ); ?></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
```

No matter if there's a previous or next link, the li's always show. Is there a way to wrap this li's around a conditional to only show if "Previous" or "Next" posts exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is really more PHP than WordPress. You just need to reorder things and add some logic:

```
$next = get_next_posts_link( 'Previous', $the_query->max_num_pages );
$previous = get_previous_posts_link( 'Next' );
if(!empty($next)) {
  $links[] = '<li class="next">'.$next.'</li>';
}
if(!empty($previous)) {
  $links[] = '<li class="previous">'.$previous.'</li>';
}
if (!empty($links)) { ?>
  <nav class="post-nav clear clearfix">
    <ul><?php
      echo implode($links); ?>
    </ul>
  </nav><?php
}
```